# what test case am i failing for the code-wars sum of intervals problem

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
def sum_of_intervals(intervals):
    new_arr = []
    ans = 0
    re_arr=sorted(intervals)
    # Find overlapping arrays
    arr = re_arr.pop(0)
    for i in range(len(intervals)):
        if i == len(intervals)-1: # To append the last value into the new_array
            new_arr.append(arr) 
            break
        for arrays in re_arr:
            if arr[1] >= arrays[0]: # Overlapping arrays
                arr=[min(arr[0],arrays[0]),max(arr[1],arrays[1])]
                re_arr[0] = arr
            else: # Not overlapping
                new_arr.append(arr)
                arr = re_arr.pop(0)
    # remove repetitive numbers
    final_arr = []
    for i in new_arr:
        if i not in final_arr:
            final_arr.append(i)
            ans += i[1]-i[0]
    return final_arr,ans
```

I submitted my solution but failed some of the test cases
I dont know any test case this code wouldn't pass for in the problem
This is a link to the problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52b7ed099cdc285c300001cd/train/python

Comment: which part of the question are you actually stuck on ?  too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I noticed my code was not efficient. I only needed one for loop, and i was not setting the proper values in : arr = re_arr.pop(0) should hvae been arr = array. I debugged and got a solution finally, Thank you